# Mostrar modal mientras se ejecuta otro metodo del controlador y muestra sus elementos

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter-3

Hola buenos días tengo el siguiente problema.
Tengo un controlador **reg_calls_controller.php** el cual tiene su **función index** y cargar la vista **reg_calls_view.php**, en el html tengo varias cosas entre esas un **botón** que **llama** a una la siguiente **función de JavaScript** .

```
function msj_cargando() {
            $('#modalLoad').modal('show');

            $.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo base_url('index.php/reg_calls_controller/todas_calls/')?>",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                //alert(data);
                $('#modalLoad').modal('hide');  
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
                $('#modalLoad').modal('hide');
                swal({
                  title: "Error!",
                  text: "La conexion no fue exitosa!",
                  icon: "error",
                  button: true,
                  dangerMode: false,
                });
            }
        });

        }
```

En el JS primero muestro la siguiente modal que esta que está en **reg_calls_view.php** y la utilizo como un loading.

```html
<div id="modalLoad" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
     <!-- Modal content-->
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-body text-center"">
         <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x"></i>
         <p><h3>Cargando...</h3></p>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
       </div>
     </div>

   </div>
 </div>
```

Pero lo que intento hacer es que se **muestre** esa **modal** mientras llamo la función **todas_calls** que esta igual en  **reg_calls_controller.php** y esta función a la vez haga una consulta los resultados los mande a la vista **todas_calls_view.php** y finalmente se cierre la modal.

```
public function todas_calls() {

  $sess_array = array(
    'id_user' => $this->session->userdata['sess_data']['id_user'],
    'username' => $this->session->userdata['sess_data']['username']
  );

  $data = array();
  $data['sess_data'] = $sess_array;

  $data['todas_calls']  = $this->reg_calls_model->todas_calls();

  $data['menu_higher'] = $this->load->view('elementos/menu_higher_view.php', $data, TRUE);
  $data['menu_left'] = $this->load->view('elementos/menu_left_view.php', '', TRUE);

  echo json_encode($data);

  $this->load->view("todas_calls_view.php", $data);

}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar.